# Percentage of work days in a month

Tags: code-golf, date

Given a year and a month, find out the percentage of work days in said 
month. Work days are Monday through Friday with no regard to holidays or 
other special things. The Gregorian calendar is used.

**Input**

A year and month in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM). The year always has four 
digits, the month always has two digits. The given year will not be before 
1582.

**Output**

Output is the percentage of work days (according to above definition) in 
the given month, rounded to a whole number. No percent sign or fractional 
digits follow.

**Sample 1**

```
Input                Output

2010-05              68
```

**Sample 2**

```
Input                Output

2010-06              73
```

**Sample 3**

```
Input                Output

1920-10              68
```

**Sample 4**

```
Input                Output

2817-12              68
```

A week has passed, an answer has been accepted. For the curious, the sizes of the submissions we got in our contest:

> 129 – Z shell
>   174 – VB.NET
>   222 – C
>   233 – C
>   300 – C

As well as our own (unranked) solutions:

> 75 – [PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/percentage-of-work-days-in-a-month/1192#1192)
>     93 – Ruby
>   112 – Bourne shell

Comment: I'm a graduate student, so... `echo 100`

Comment: Even grad students cannot escape the fundamental definitions in their line of work. And I defined work days differently ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 64-bit Perl, 67 <s>68</s>

Perl 5.10 or later, run with `perl -E 'code here'` or `perl -M5.010 filename`

```
map{$d++,/^S/||$w++if$_=`date -d@ARGV-$_`}1..31;say int.5+100*$w/$d
```

Concessions to code size:

- locale-sensitive: it counts as work days the days whose `date` output don't start with a capital S.  Run under `LC_ALL=C` if in doubt.
- output is pure and well-formatted, but there's "garbage" on stderr on months shorter than 31.  `2> /dev/null` if upset.
- <s>for some reason, my version of `date` considers 2817-12 an invalid month.  Who knew, GNU new apocalypse is due!</s> Requires a 64 bit build of `date` for dates after 2038.  (Thanks Joey)

Comment: Apparently it was abolished by "Siphous Hemes" during his rule. ref ["A new history of the Holy Bible"](http://books.google.com/books?id=b55HAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA438&lpg=PA438&dq=%22year+2817%22&source=bl&ots=QPnjIeOCym&sig=kTQJc9vRI1Qb13o-VqyJljQc0q0&hl=en&ei=XhtmTbWCF4T2swOi1qj-BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22year%202817%22&f=false)

Comment: Is every year after 2038 broken? Then switching t a 64-bit build might help due to some braindead-ness with date handling ;-)

Comment: @Joey that's exactly it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: JB: Was just a guess and I actually didn't expect anything beyond C to still use solely 32-bit integers that count seconds since a weird epoch. Though, to be honest, I put the requirement about dates > 2038 in there for exactly this purpose ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP - 135

I made it in PHP because I had a [similar problem to treat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963205/how-can-i-figure-out-the-number-of-week-days-in-a-month) a few days ago.

```
<?php $a=array(2,3,3,3,2,1,1);$t=strtotime($argv[1]);$m=date(t,$t);echo round((20+min($m-28,$a[date(w,strtotime('28day',$t))]))/$m*100)
```

(Somewhat) More legibly, and without notices about constants being used as strings:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$additionalDays = array(2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1);
$timestamp = strtotime($argv[1]);
$daysInMonth = date('t', $timestamp);
$limit = $daysInMonth - 28;
$twentyNinthDayIndex = date('w', strtotime("+28 days", $timestamp));
$add = $additionalDays[$twentyNinthDayIndex];
$numberOfWorkDays = 20 + min($limit, $add);
echo round($numberOfWorkDays / $daysInMonth * 100);
?>
```

This is made possible by a very simple algorithm to compute the number of work days in a month: check for the weekdayness of the 29th, 30th and 31st (if those dates exist), and add 20.

Comment: Great algorithm, poor golfing. Using contemporary PHP 5.3.5 and `-R`, this approach can be golfed down to 86 bytes (63.7%): `$a="2333211";echo.5+min(-8+$m=date(t,$t=strtotime($argn)),20+$a[date(w,$t)])/$m*100|0;`
[See the golfing steps.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f11e53287c5a39b8cdf64cf11e82fa0657648ad7)

Comment: 80 bytes: `<?=.5+min(-8+$m=date(t,$t=strtotime($argn)),20+(5886>>date(w,$t)*2&3))/$m*100|0;`

Answer (score 3):

## Swift, 346 bytes

Short version:

```
func f(_ s:String)->Int{let c=Calendar.current,m=Int(s.suffix(2))!,y=Int(s.prefix(4))!,mR=c.range(of:.day,in:.month,for:DateComponents(calendar:c,year:y,month:m).date!)!,n=mR.reduce(0){p,d in let d=c.date(from: DateComponents(year:y,month:m,day:d))!,w=c.component(.weekday,from:d);return(2...6).contains(w) ?p+1:p};return (n*1000/mR.count+5)/10}
```

Slightly longer version:

```
func f2(_ s: String) -> Int {
    let c=Calendar.current
    let m=Int(s.suffix(2))!
    let y=Int(s.prefix(4))!
    let mR=c.range(of:.day,in:.month,for:DateComponents(calendar:c,year:y,month:m).date!)!
    let n=mR.reduce(0){p,d in
        let d=c.date(from: DateComponents(year:y,month:m,day:d))!
        let w=c.component(.weekday,from:d)
        return(2...6).contains(w) ?p+1:p
    }
    return (n*1000/mR.count+5)/10
}
```

Comment: That's not the most golf-friendly of languages, is it? ;-)

Comment: @Joey yes indeed - sometimes it feels like hoping one does not come in last place :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Python 152 Characters**

```
from calendar import*
y,m=map(int,raw_input().split('-'))
c=r=monthrange(y,m)[1]
for d in range(1,r+1):
 if weekday(y,m,d)>4:c-=1
print '%.f'%(c*100./r)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, 80

```
$x=$args;1..31|%{"$x-$_"|date -u %u -ea 0}|%{$a++
$b+=!!($_%6)}
[int]($b*100/$a)
```

Comment: Are you sure `[int]` really rounds? I'd tend to believe it floors.

Comment: @zneak: PowerShell is not C or a C-derived language. It uses the default rounding mode of .NET which is »round to nearest even integer«. Just try it out: Both `[int]1.5` and `[int]2.5` yield `2`. This exact behaviour often causes problems in tasks where floored division is necessary (which then requires an extra `[Math]::Floor()`), but in this case it doesn't hurt and »round to even« only applies to numbers that end in `.5` which cannot happen here.

Comment: If you're sure then I believe you. I just expected it to work like C# instead, and I don't have any Windows machine on which to test at home.

Comment: @zneak: No, definitely doesn't work like in C#. Something like `[int]` in PowerShell is usually more a conversion than a cast :-). Things like `[int[]][char[]]'abc'` also work which you can't get to work in many other languages.

Comment: Necrobump but `$input` -> `$args` saves a byte.

Comment: @Veskah Just curious... did you get here the same way I did? (PPCG Graduation Userscript Challenges of the Day -> Has my milk expired -> related challenges -> here)

Comment: @Veskah: Usually on my challenges I'd get in the same arguments with you as with mazzy, but in this case I actually left it unspecified so it's an option here, indeed :-)

Comment: @Veskah: Apparently parameter validation has become more strict in the meantime and we need a bit more code to remove the error messages, sadly.

Comment: Bummer, guess I should've let sleeping dogs lie.

Answer (score 1):

## D: 186 Characters

```
auto f(S)(S s){auto d=Date.fromISOExtendedString(s~"-28"),e=d.endOfMonth;int n=20;while(1){d+=dur!"days"(1);if(d>e)break;int w=d.dayOfWeek;if(w>0&&w<6)++n;}return rndtol(n*100.0/e.day);}
```

More Legibly:

```
auto f(S)(S s)
{
    auto d = Date.fromISOExtendedString(s ~ "-28"), e = d.endOfMonth;
    int n = 20;

    while(1)
    {
        d += dur!"days"(1);

        if(d > e)
            break;

        int w = d.dayOfWeek;

        if(w > 0 && w < 6)
            ++n;
    }

    return rndtol(n * 100.0 / e.day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 142

```
from calendar import*
y,m=map(int,raw_input().split('-'))
f,r=monthrange(y,m)
print'%.f'%((r-sum(weekday(y,m,d+1)>4for d in range(r)))*100./r)
```

Thanks to fR0DDY for the calendar bit.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <strike>124</strike> <strike>119</strike> 111

```
require 'date'
e=Date.civil *$*[0].split(?-).map(&:to_i),-1
p ((e+1<<1..e).count{|d|d.cwday<6}*1e2/e.day).round
```

Requires Ruby 1.9 due to splatting the year and month before the -1 "day" argument and `?-` for `"-"`. For Ruby 1.8, we must add 2 characters:

```
require 'date'
e=Date.civil *$*[0].split('-').map(&:to_i)<<-1
p ((e+1<<1..e).count{|d|d.cwday<6}*1e2/e.day).round
```

**Edit**: Shave five characters based on @Dogbert's help.
**Edit**: Shave eight more characters based on @steenslag's help.

Comment: Why are you assigning Date to D?

Comment: @Dogbert Whoops! Holdover from a time when I had two Date.civils; thanks!

Comment: `'-'` could be written as `?-` in Ruby 1.9

Comment: @Dogbert Nice. I'll throw that in, too. I feel there must be a shorter way to pick the week days, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: e+1<<1 is three shorter than e-e.day+1

Comment: (d.wday+1)%7>1 can be replaced by d.cwday<6

Comment: @steenslag Those are both great, thank you. I didn't know about `Date#<<` previously; very cool.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 82 bytes

```
f()(cal -NMd$1|sed -n "s/^$2.//p"|wc -w)
dc -e`f $1 "[^S ]"`d`f $1 S`+r200*r/1+2/p
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5.2, 88 bytes

Although I already golfed [zneak´s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1217/55735) down to 85 bytes (I just found one more), here´s my own:
<sub>I doubt that I can squeeze another three bytes out here.</sub>

```php
$a=_4444444255555236666304777411;echo$a[date(t,$t=strtotime($argn))%28*7+date(N,$t)]+67;
```

takes input from STDIN: Run with `echo <yyyy>-<mm> | php -nR '<code>'`.

The string `$a` maps days per month (`date(t)`) and week day of the first day of the month (`date(N)`: Monday=1, Sunday=7) to the percentage of work days-67; `strtotime` converts the input to a UNIX timestamp; the rest of the code does the hashing.

+1 byte for older PHP 5: Replace `N` with `w` and `$a=_...;` with `$a="..."`.
another +3 bytes for PHP 4: insert `.-1` after `$argn`.

-5 bytes for PHP 5.5 or later (postdates the challenge):
Remove everything before `echo` and replace `$a` with `"4444444255555236666304777411"`.

Comment: Well ... one byte: `%7` instead of `%28`.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 158 bytes

```
s=>{var d=DateTime.Parse(s);int i=0,t=DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year,d.Month),w=0;while(i<t)w-=-(int)d.AddDays(i++).DayOfWeek%6>>31;return Math.Round(1e2*w/t);};
```

Anonymous method which returns the required percentage.

Full program with ungolfed, commented method and test cases:

```
using System;

class WorkingDayPercentage
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func <string, double> f =
        s =>
        {
            var d = DateTime.Parse(s);                      // extracts a DateTime object from the supplied string
            int i = 0,                                      // index variable
                t = DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month),  // number of total number of days in the specified month
                w = 0;                                      // number of working days in the month
            
            while (i < t)                                   // iterates through the days of the month
                w -= -(int)d.AddDays(i++).DayOfWeek%6 >> 31;// d.AddDays(i) is the current day
                                                            // i++ increments the index variable to go to the next day
                                                            // .DayOfWeek is an enum which hold the weekdays
                                                            // (int)..DayOfWeek gets the days's index in the enum
                                                            // note that 6 is Saturday, 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday etc.
                                                            // (int)DayOfWeek % 6 converts weekend days to 0
                                                            // while working days stay strictly positive
                                                            // - changes the sign of the positive numbers
                                                            // >> 31 extracts the signum
                                                            // which is -1 for negative numbers (working days)
                                                            // weekend days remain 0
                                                            // w -= substracts the negative numbers
                                                            // equivalent to adding their modulus
            
            return Math.Round(1e2 * w / t);                 // the Math.round function requires a double or a decimal
                                                            // working days and total number of days are integers
                                                            // also, a percentage must be returned
                                                            // multiplying with 100.0 converts the expression to a double
                                                            // however, 1e2 is used to shorten the code
        };
        
        // test cases:
        Console.WriteLine(f("2010-05")); // 68
        Console.WriteLine(f("2010-06")); // 73
        Console.WriteLine(f("1920-10")); // 68
        Console.WriteLine(f("2817-12")); // 68
    }
}
```

Alternative function, which adds negative values to the number of working days, changing the sign in the return with no extra byte cost:

```
s=>{var d=DateTime.Parse(s);int i=0,t=DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year,d.Month),w=0;while(i<t)w+=-(int)d.AddDays(i++).DayOfWeek%6>>31;return-Math.Round(1e2*w/t);};
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 55 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⌊.5+100×2÷/(2 5)2{≢⍎⍕↓⍺↓¯2⌽' ',cal⍎' '@5⊢⍵⊣⎕CY'dfns'}¨⊂
```

`⊂` enclose date to treat it as a whole

`(2 5)2{`…`}¨` apply the following function on that, but with the left arguments `[2,5]` and `2`:

`⎕CY'dfns'` copy the "dfns" library

`⍵⊣` discard the report in favour of the date

`' '@5⊢` replace the 5th character (`-`) with a space

`⍎` execute that to get two-element list

`cal` call the calendar function on that

`' ',` prepend a column of spaces to that

`¯2⌽` rotate the last two columns (Saturday) to the front

`⍺↓` drop left-argument number of rows (2, headers) and columns (if specified; 5=Sat+Sun)

`↓` split matrix into list of lines

`⍕` format (flattens with insertion of double-spacing)

`⍎` execute (turns remaining day numbers into a flat numeric list)

`≢` tally those

`2÷/` divide each pair (there's only one)

`100×` multiply by a hundred

`.5+` add a half

`⌊` floor

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FPl56ptqGBweHpRoe362sYKZhqGlU/6lz0qLfvUe/UR22TH/XuApKH1hs96tmrrqCuk5yYA5QDshxMH3UBlW191LX4Ud9U50j1lLS8YvXaQysedTX9T3vUNgFkRN9UT/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P9p6kYGhga6BqbqXDCmGYhpaGlkoGtoABa1MDTXNTRSBwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 243 bytes

```go
import(."time";."math")
func f(s string)int{t,_:=Parse("2006-01",s)
D,o:=Hour*24,0.0
y,m,_:=t.Date()
d:=Date(y,m+1,0,0,0,0,0,UTC).Add(D).Sub(t).Hours()/24
for;t.Month()==m;t=t.Add(D){if w:=t.Weekday();0<w&&w<6{o++}}
return int(Round(100*o/d))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVHBbhMxEBVXf4VlKZWn8brepaQhySJVRIgLUkVBHKBql9ibWs3a0e5soyrKl3CJkPio8hv8APYuVArYBz8_z7x54_n2fen3j7N1sbgrloZWhXWE2Grta5SsrJA9XRqsrVs2B8TCu3v2o8UyGT_-6nkuGdrKsKlkVYG3DEjZugUteUN7BbAOtyiuJ_lFUTeGs0ypUaJSJhogc-En-Vvf1sfZqVBSkQdRxVCU8wINB6IneYcCP0yFetofP7wGea41n4O8bL9yBBllGg4n2SkpfT1F-c47vOWQ59UUg2IfvbUl3cQCn4y508UDh6mabY6ONrPR1g-Hux2pDba1o8E2f-9bp3mq1LE_0QC7vvWfz7Kux_h5HOiWWLdusaGTnN5kKlWJekEP1mhMen50yJ89J-nLTCWp-j9-nJ4lafYvfxNbo9diZZ2J9erChSlerlcWee9CsC-ORVOlNSvdmXrTIR5zIHgV1Ee2f_-srsRfmF4R34ZJxddz9JZ7IEuPXXBQB3IR5oklZ4OGJq8oH2igAx3Oewg1Be2kgwANSR2ieR4xkB3583X7fX_-Bg)

Loops through the days of the month and checks each for being a weekday (between `0=Sunday` and `6=Saturday`).

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol - <strike>118</strike> 113

```
w: b: 0 o: d: do join input"-01"while[d/2 = o/2][if d/7 < 6[++ w]++ b d: o + b]print to-integer round w / b * 100
```

Ungolfed:

```
w: b: 0 
o: d: do join input "-01"
while [d/2 = o/2] [
    if d/7 < 6 [++ w]
    ++ b
    d: o + b
]
print to-integer round w / b * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL, 110 bytes

```
select round(100*sum(1-trunc(to_char(x+level-1,'d')/6))/sum(1))from dual,t connect by level<=add_months(x,1)-x
```

It works with an assumption that input data is stored in a table in using `date` data type, e.g.

```
with t as (select to_date('2010-06','yyyy-mm') x from dual)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 78 bytes

```perl6
{round 100*@_.grep(6>*.day-of-week)/@_}o{Date.new("$_-01")...^*.month-*.month}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsIwEEDRvacIQSQNzDhTMCqidOE5DIGmFrRNqZUSSs8eXbioqw@P3/n@aVITxaYSZ5GmPrzbUjCRLizee98pc9FYugihgtH7R7Yt7Bymqxs8tn5Ucm2BWGaIeNPYhHao4dc5vVwUlZI5MQHtZHZa/YlZCB9zAqblc@A9cP6V9AE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>36</s> 34 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
HÆÐU+XnÃf@¤¤ÅÉ¶XÎÃme
èÈ©n6Ã*L/UÊ r
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=SMbQVStYbsNmQKSkxcm2WM7DbWUK6MipbjbDKkwvVcogcg&input=IjIwMTAtMDYi)

Not pretty at all! Needs more work.

### <s>34</s> 32 bytes

2 bytes can be saved by always rounding down as the challenge doesn't specify that we must round to the nearest integer:

```
HÆÐU+XnÃf@¤¤ÅÉ¶XÎÃme
èÈ©n6ÃzUÊ/L
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=SMbQVStYbsNmQKSkxcm2WM7DbWUK6MipbjbDelXKL0w&input=IjIwMTAtMDYi)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + ncal, <s>75</s> 70 bytes

```sh
m=`ncal ${1#*-} ${1%-*}`
set $m
wc -w<<<${m%%Sa*}|dc -e ?7-A0*$#\ 9-/p
```

We start by using `ncal` to print a calendar:

```
    May 2010          
Mo     3 10 17 24 31
Tu     4 11 18 25   
We     5 12 19 26   
Th     6 13 20 27   
Fr     7 14 21 28   
Sa  1  8 15 22 29   
Su  2  9 16 23 30
```

The total number of days in the month is the word-count of this output, minus 9 (the seven weekday names and the month and year of the header).  This word-count is obtained using `set` and `$#`.

The number of work days is a similar calculation, but we first eliminate everything from `Sa` onwards (we can't just match `S` because the month may be `Sep`), and subtract only 7 surplus words.  We count this using `wc`.

We then use `dc` to compute a percentage (using `A0` as short form of `100`).

Note that this program rounds fractional percentages downwards - the question's examples appear to use a different choice for the rounding, but it didn't impose a specific direction.  Rounding to nearest would cost an additional 7 bytes by executing `$#\ 2/+` before we divide by the total: `?7-A0*$#\ 2/+$#\ 9-/p`.

Answer (score 0):

## GNU date+bc, 56 bytes

### Abstract

This Answer demonstrates that the following 56-byte shell pipeline
calculates the percentage of work days in a given month, rounded to
the nearest whole percent:

```sh
date -d$1-1month-4week +'70+%d-3*(%w+1<%d)-3*(%u<%d)'|bc
```

### Analysis

There are 28 possible monthly calendars, that can be identified
according to the last day/date of the month:

|  | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **28th** | 20/28 | 20/28 | 20/28 | 20/28 | 20/28 | 20/28 | 20/28 |
| **29th** | 21/29 | 21/29 | 21/29 | 21/29 | 21/29 | 20/29 | 20/29 |
| **30th** | 21/30 | 22/30 | 22/30 | 22/30 | 22/30 | 21/30 | 20/30 |
| **31st** | 21/31 | 22/31 | 23/31 | 23/31 | 23/31 | 22/31 | 21/31 |

There are nine distinct fractions here, that can be converted to
percentages:

|  | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **28** | 71 |  |  |  |
| **29** | 69 | 72 |  |  |
| **30** | 67 | 70 | 73 |  |
| **31** |  | 68 | 71 | 74 |

Substituting these gives our conversion table:

|  | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28th | 71 | 71 | 71 | 71 | 71 | 71 | 71 |
| 29th | 72 | 72 | 72 | 72 | 72 | 69 | 69 |
| 30th | 70 | 73 | 73 | 73 | 73 | 70 | 67 |
| 31st | 68 | 71 | 74 | 74 | 74 | 71 | 68 |

The pattern becomes more clearly evident when we split this into a
basic value for a month containing four weekends, less an amount for a
fifth Saturday and for a fifth Sunday:

|  | Basic | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28th | 71 | . . | . . | . . | . . | . . | . . | . . |
| 29th | 72 | . . | . . | . -3 | -3 . | . . | . . | . . |
| 30th | 73 | . . | . . | . -3 | -3 -3 | -3 . | . . | . . |
| 31st | 74 | . . | . . | . -3 | -3 -3 | -3 -3 | -3 . | . . |

The basic value is clearly 71 plus one for each day more than 28 days.

And we must then subtract 3 if the last day is in a range beginning
Saturday and having length equal to those excess days, less three for
a similar range beginning Sunday.

### Implementation

Firstly, we append a day number to turn year and month into a full
date: `$1-01`.

Rather than finding the *last* day of the month, we select a date
nearer the start of the month, by subtracting 28 days from the start
of the following month.  This gives us a day-of-week that's one later
than used in the analysis section:

```sh
date -d'$1-01 +1month-4week'
```

Using this date, we then format a calculation for `bc` to execute and
print.  The basic percentage is simple; it's just 70 more than the day
number we landed on: `70+%d`.

The adjustments for extra weekend days are then computed using a pair
of inequalities, taking advantage of the fact that there are two
representations for day-of-week, with Sunday represented as 0 or
as 7.  We subtract 3 points from the basic percentage for each of
those inequalities.

### Demo

We can reproduce the results from the examples in the question:

| Command | Result |
| --- | --- |
| [`./1158 2010-05`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBN0XFUNcwNz@vJEPXpDw1NVtBW93cQFs1RddYS0O1XNvQRjVFE8wuBbHUa5KS////b2RgaKBrYAoA) | 68 |
| [`./1158 2010-06`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBN0XFUNcwNz@vJEPXpDw1NVtBW93cQFs1RddYS0O1XNvQRjVFE8wuBbHUa5KS////b2RgaKBrYAYA) | 73 |
| [`./1158 1920-10`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBN0XFUNcwNz@vJEPXpDw1NVtBW93cQFs1RddYS0O1XNvQRjVFE8wuBbHUa5KS////b2hpZKBraAAA) | 68 |
| [`./1158 2817-12`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBN0XFUNcwNz@vJEPXpDw1NVtBW93cQFs1RddYS0O1XNvQRjVFE8wuBbHUa5KS////b2RhaK5raAQA) | 68 |

And we can show that we get the correct [results for all 28 shapes of
month](https://tio.run/##RVBBasMwELz7FQOJcFNnzUpOmxb6i54KvSiW3JgkUrBl0hLn7arsFLqw7MweZpjZ6X4fF3i3R1sHeGdx8i7s4RtYXe9xtO4rUe0MrDNk9A8a3yHYPmTZhFq0DsuHc9e60CAX/afLofh6ZS5Lrm505aospbqt54/a3IhVWlnMRiQnyTHD/xgdLKghFLn4IHESQRiIAULnGNH7LoAOal2BhsTrIdFGrjLjZ5HeBizbeBcxS0ny7rO5WHtIklsuhKHq8UFcCvkmzGrGw4TycVdHM3UwouvB2AKLKe5Jh5QyeGgEvTtaJJh@qR4/dLDf59SdDq13MSqWTPz0d5@jfFVMkqN6kVuS6hc)
shown in the first table:

```sh
for i in $(printf '%s\n' 20{{00..03}-{03..12},{00..24}-02}-01+month-1day |
           date -f- +'%Y-%m%t%d %u %a' | sort -k2,3 -u | cut -f1)
do ./1158 $i
done | rs 0 7
```

```
71  71  71  71  71  71  71
72  72  72  72  72  69  69
70  73  73  73  73  70  67
68  71  74  74  74  71  68
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 152 bytes

A port of [@adrianmp's C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111902/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9Pa8JAEMXv@RSDp91K4q6l0UZXKHgVD6UtpZQymk1cGxPZHRURP3u62xZa@uc27/3eMG/cEitszWbbWII17jEhs9HJS/TLIh0crDyLmsVaLwlmaGo4RQC5LmDjBUNbugxurMXj0y1ZU5fPPIO72hAon/RR2GMFRcY@qJpMm92i0ly1Tk1OgeXq6@ajRjtralolW7ROM8dHIUIqTypdl7SaF@/YuxYOSoyKxjIzjgVQAxRLbgqWJ0hTPDLTlTwpdZjnxYPWr0HcY7XT45QfukqOZugP2WZX50wKkYiLQ4/4ufWdodcD0o5giU67LLwBW9@fqpoVrNMXUsTiqsN5CKbDv3n6yQeXP7m87otYiv/3h3IQy/53fo7O7Rs)

```scala
s=>{val d=java.time.YearMonth.parse(s);val t=d.lengthOfMonth;var w=0;for(i<-0 to t-1)if(d.atDay(i+1).getDayOfWeek.getValue<6)w+=1;Math.round(100.0*w/t)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHRTsIwFIbv9xQnXJBNstFiBF0YCQkx8WKSaNQQY8yBdaMwNtJ2GGJ49tmxOYfi1XrO9/3taScXGGOe8802FQpWuENH8Q1z3o0/LcWKDsaaGel8xRYKfOQJfBoAAQthowsTRSRdGAuB@9dHJXgSvVkuPCVcgXc0AXYYQ@hCScEbwSTN5jHTXBZVKZVaoJszhsJPE7V0tigkM6XVEFSqMJ7gXichcGKWRGo5DY96bQn4SMVan1V5xKhQmAowOQxtIJAlije2s@oxqkFwPw1fGFsfz0GlHZ3sALWciBVVSesMD8GsM4XyjHHGYORB7Tr@9H4ynv3AdhvORIbNyO3DXTPSnBJObtnxgNboYHx/q4WP@jVFmiWBSQlxCFychLuNdzAawa4GTCpYoGTSPba2@h@qODFDs9UjlNjkqmVZhdi/Ps/7FR9c/ub0pkdsSv7PX9OBTXtNfjAOef4F)

```scala
import java.time._
import java.time.temporal._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f: String => Double = s => {
      val d = YearMonth.parse(s)
      val totalDays = d.lengthOfMonth
      var workingDays = 0

      for (i <- 0 until totalDays) {
        val dayOfWeek = d.atDay(i + 1).getDayOfWeek
        if (dayOfWeek.getValue >= DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue && dayOfWeek.getValue <= DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getValue) {
          workingDays += 1
        }
      }

      Math.round(100.0 * workingDays / totalDays)
    }

    // test cases:
    println(f("2010-05")) // 68
    println(f("2010-06")) // 73
    println(f("1920-10")) // 68
    println(f("2817-12")) // 68
  }
}
```